# Why is Pamac not detecting software updates for some programs?

Tags: software-updates, antergos

There is an update for Cura.
[image: Screenshot update for Cura]

There is an update for Visual Studio Code.
[image: there is an update for Visual Studio Code]

But Pamac keeps telling me that the system is up-to-date.
[image]

I'm using Antergos with KDE.

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 antergos is up to date
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are persons maintaining those packages in the Arch/Antergos repositories. You access the repos via `pacman` or `pamac`. I'm sure they are preparing those updates already for you so that you can install them right away. Have a little patience. They ensure that the installation runs smoothly on many systems.

Comment: I see [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/cura/) that the update was released and flagged out-of-date 3 weeks ago. I don't really understand why it is so hard or why they need more than 3 weeks to ensure that the installation runs smoothly on many systems.

Comment: You are free to install the software without the package manager.